# NHibernate Or Exists

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I am having trouble converting the following to Sql to nhibernate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Booking.*
FROM   Booking WHERE  Booking.Status = 2
            OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   JourneyFuture
            WHERE  JourneyFuture.BookingId = Booking.BookingId
                    AND ((JourneyFuture.[IsDriverAssigned] = 0
                        AND JourneyFuture.[Status] = 1) -- live
                        OR JourneyFuture.[Status] = 2
                        OR JourneyFuture.[Status] = 4
                        OR (JourneyFuture.[Status] = 1
                            AND (JourneyFuture.IsMetricCalculated = 0
                                    OR JourneyFuture.Duration = 0
                                    OR JourneyFuture.Distance = 0))))
```

Here is what I have so far with Nhibernate:

```
Booking bookingAlias = null;    
var journeyFuture = QueryOver.Of<JourneyFuture>().Where(x=> x.Booking.Id==bookingAlias.Id).
                    And(x => (!x.IsDriverAssigned && x.Status==JourneyStatusType.Live) || x.Status==JourneyStatusType.CancelRequested
                                || x.Status == JourneyStatusType.Modified || 
                                (x.Status == JourneyStatusType.Live && (!x.IsMetricCalculated || x.Duration==0 || x.Distance==0)))
                                .Select(x=> x.Booking);

                var result = session.QueryOver<Booking>(() => bookingAlias)
                    .Where(x => x.Status == BookingStatusType.CancelRequested)
                    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(journeyFuture)
                    .List<Booking>();
```

This however is producing an "And" exists which makes sense, but how do I get an OR EXISTS?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Booking bookingAlias = null;    
var journeyFuture = QueryOver.Of<JourneyFuture>().Where(x=> x.Booking.Id==bookingAlias.Id).
    And(x => (!x.IsDriverAssigned && x.Status==JourneyStatusType.Live) || x.Status==JourneyStatusType.CancelRequested
                || x.Status == JourneyStatusType.Modified || 
                (x.Status == JourneyStatusType.Live && (!x.IsMetricCalculated || x.Duration==0 || x.Distance==0)))
                .Select(x=> x.Booking);

var result = session.QueryOver<Booking>(() => bookingAlias)
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Or(
            Restrictions.Where(() => bookingAlias.Status == BookingStatusType.CancelRequested),
            Subqueries.Exists(journeyFuture.DetachedCriteria)))
    .List<Booking>();
```

Basically replace `.WithSubquery` with the more powerful `Restrictions.Or` and `Subqueries.Exists`. I wish there was a way to do this with `.WithSubquery`, but I'm not sure there is.

In general, with complex restrictions, you can dip down into the `Restrictions` class. The downside to this is that it usually makes your code more complex.